# How to make an installer for visual c# 2010 express projects?

Tags: c#

How do I make an installer for the applications I made in visual c# 2010 express? Do I have to purchase the full version? I downloaded wix but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. I wrote a little program that helps with stat point allocation in a game me and my friends play, but I can't figure out how to share it with them now.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: You could simply ask a question concerning your problems with wix. The way your question is stated right now is overly broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the installers available in higher versions in Visual Studio, trust me.
There are many known problems in these installers (ex. prerequisites, internationalization, customization).

I would recomment using:

- inno setup
- wix
- nsis

or other tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party installer solutions, such as [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), to (relatively) easily make installations.

Otherwise, upgrading to VS 2010 Professional or higher will provide you with the ability to make Setup Projects.  I would not recommend upgrading just for these, however, as VS 2012 dropped Setup Projects, so eventually finding a 3rd party installer is a good idea.